# Impossible to create a topic on KAFKA

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, spring-kafka

I try to create a topic on apache KAFKA automatically with spring boot JAVA. For that I followed this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-kafka
But I manage to connect to the server, but I can't create a topic.
The KAFKA server is hosted on an EC2 AWS instance.

Here is a part of the error obtained in the Intellij console

```
022-05-08 10:21:22.889  WARN 20424 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Error connecting to node ip-172-31-XX-XX.eu-west-2.compute.internal:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)

java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-172-31-XX.XX.eu-west-2.compute.internal
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:797) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.DefaultHostResolver.resolve(DefaultHostResolver.java:27) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.resolve(ClientUtils.java:110) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:511) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.access$200(ClusterConnectionStates.java:468) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:173) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:979) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.ready(NetworkClient.java:301) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.sendEligibleCalls(KafkaAdminClient.java:1127) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.processRequests(KafkaAdminClient.java:1387) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.run(KafkaAdminClient.java:1330) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

[image: image capture from offset explorer]

Here my code :

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaTopicConfig {
    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Bean
    public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
        configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic1() {
        return new NewTopic("baeldung", 1, (short) 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I had not properly configured the config/server.properties file of Apache KAFKA.
Uncomment the following lines:
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092

replace "you.host.name" with the "public ip address" of the EC2 server where Apache KAFKA is installed.
Open port 9092.

listeners is what the broker will use to create the server sockets.

advertised.listeners is what the clients will use to connect to the brokers.